# What is the sufficient condition for having at least one Eigenvalue equal to 0?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In one of my differential equation exams at college I came up with this question:

Can you find a sufficient condition for a square matrix to have at least one Eigenvalue equal to 0?

for small matrices It's easy to see if at least a row is duplicate (or the matrix has at least two rows in which the elements are completely negative to each other) the matrix will have one eigenvalue equal to zero:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 a & b\\
 -a & -b
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + (b-a)\lambda - ab + ab = \lambda(\lambda+(b-a))
$$
but I can't state a generalized proof for any matrix of $n \times n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Consider the determinant.  Did you mean $n\times n$ where you typed $m\times n$?

Comment: thank you @J.W.Tanner, it was &n \times n& and I edited it.

Comment: There are plenty of equivalent conditions. E.g. a square matrix has eigenvalue zero if and only if it is not injective, if and only if it is not surjective, if and only if it is not invertible, if and only if its rows are not linearly independent, if and only if its columns are not linearly independent.

Comment: thanks @Semiclassical, it's 3 am here and I misspelled that.) It's edited now.

Comment: Hint: The determinant of a square matrix is equal to the product of its eigenvalues.